# Failed to use SFTP to update files on Windows 10 running the OpenSSH server

Tags: windows-10, permissions, openssh, sftp, mobaxterm

I want to work remotely on a win10 machine by SSH.

I started the OpenSSH server service following the directions at:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse
The account I used in this server has the windows admin privilege.

My local machine is also win10 based. I used mobaxterm as the ssh client. The connection is successful and mobaxterm's sftp directory on the left shows the file hierarchy in the remote machine.

But when I edit a remote file and try to save it, the uploading process to update the original takes forever with no success. The remote file is not read-only, on the mobaxterm's sftp bar it shows a 677 permission.

How could I change my configuration of the server to make the files could be remotely edited by mobaxterm's sftp?

Thank you!

Comment: You are authenticating as a user on the remote machine or a user on the local machine?

Comment: Hi Ramhound, I use an admin account to SSH into the remote machine.